# SQL error 1215 cannot add foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, ddl

```
     create table branch(
     brname char(20) not null,
     city char(20) not null,
     assests float(8,2) not null,
     locid int not null,
     coname char(20) not null,
     primary key(coname,brname)
     )engine=innodb;
     alter table branch
     add constraint fk_branch_city foreign key(coname,locid)
     references city(coname,locid);

     create table room(
     brname char(20) not null,
     roomnb int not null,
     costofroom float(8,2) not null,
     roomsize int not null,
     roomfloor int not null,
     primary key(roomnb,brname)
     )engine=innodb;
     alter table room
     add constraint fk_room_branch foreign key(brname)
     references branch(brname);
```

Im getting the error: sql execution error 1215, cannot add foreign constraint key( alter table room till branch(brname); is being highlighted).
So I just don't understand how should I fix this problem.

Comment: You have a composite primary key in `branch`.  You need to include all columns for the foreign key reference.  My advice is to have an integer unique key in each table and use that for foreign key references.

Comment: Do u mean the coname should be in the table room?

Comment: can you please elaborate more, like what should i do?

Comment: . . Yes, I mean `coname` should the in `room`, if you are using a composite primary key.